# Firebase FireStore @ Android - best practices for offline first

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase Firestore (Not the realtime database) and programming an android app with it.

I want my app to work as offline first, which means that when the app loads FireStore will load the data from the Chace and show it to the user, and after that query changes from the server.

To accomplish that, I am doing a normal GET request (Not listener) with source of Chace.

After the get call has completed, I am attaching a listener to listen for all the update. (Locally or from the server), so I Can present the user the updated status.

The problem with this method is that basiclly it means ***I will download the same object twice*** First time on the initial get request, and than on the initial listener. Which means I will send duplicates to the UI.

Is there any practice available in the firestore API to avoid this? So the listener will not return records that the get request has already synced?

See below example code. Thx!

GET request: (runs first)

```
db.collection(sCollection)
                .get(SOURCE.CHACE)
               .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
            });
```

Listener: (runs second)

```
m_registration = db.collection(sName).
        orderBy("stamp", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value,
                                    @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                        return;
                    }

                    for (DocumentChange dc : value.getDocumentChanges()) {

                        
                            }
                            catch(JSONException ex) {

                            }


                    }
```

Comment: I think this article, [How to drastically reduce the number of reads when no documents are changed in Firestore?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e) will help.

Answer (score -2):

The Firebase Firestore handles `offline` so good that you can use it as `oofline first` database without doing anything on your own. You can read, listen and edit data as if you are doing it synchornously. You should deffinitely check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) out.

That means you don't need to use `get` to make the `offline` better. It will work seamlesly with the `listener` to.

Comment: Generally speaking, you are right, the listener knows how to fetch the data from the check seamlessly. However, I read somewhere that it first tries to get it from the server, and only after a timeout will access the Chace. Is this true? Can this be buggy on places where the internet connection might be not stable?

Comment: If you don't have any connection it will get the data directly from the cache. If you want to make sure that you get the data from cache you could disable and enable the network access directly by yourself: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#disable_and_enable_network_access

Comment: Also check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50799518/5519300 A listener sounds like a much better solution for your usecase.

Comment: Thx! I am more confident now about using the listener.